# Need help understanding these method parameters used in the constructor

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Working on an assignment. Taking classes online and I've emailed my prof with the same question but I'm hoping to get a quicker response from you wonderful people here (as I only have 2 hours per day that I can work on school and Ive hit a roadblock).

Assignment is to finish the code for a binary search tree and blah blah implement some stuff.

I'm hung up on one chunk of code that I just cant understand.

This is a code snippet from the LinkedBinaryTree class that was provided.
 LinkedBinaryTree relies on a BinaryTreeNode class for the nodes.

```
public class LinkedBinaryTree<T> implements BinaryTreeADT<T>, Iterable<T>
{
   protected BinaryTreeNode<T> root; 
   protected int modCount;
}

//Constructors

public LinkedBinaryTree() 
{
    root = null;
}  

public LinkedBinaryTree(T element) 
{
    root = new BinaryTreeNode<T>(element);
}

public LinkedBinaryTree(T element, LinkedBinaryTree<T> left, 
        LinkedBinaryTree<T> right) 
{
    root = new BinaryTreeNode<T>(element);
    root.setLeft(left.root);
    root.setRight(right.root);
}
```

This is primarily what I fail to grasp.

**root.setLeft(left.root);**

**root.setRight(right.root);**

What is **.root** and how does that work.

The variable is being used in two places? is this some kind of recursion/magic that I just haven't encountered yet? (And currently fail to understand) If so, I will get reading let me know and point me in the right direction.

I will post the code for the BinaryTreeNode methods below. I don't understand these parameters that are being passed.

**root** is a variable of the type **BinaryTreeNode** but in its use it is passing a **LinkedBinaryTree** either **left** or **right**  as the parameters for a method that requires a variable of type **BinaryTreeNode**

```
public class BinaryTreeNode<T>{

    protected T element;
    protected BinaryTreeNode<T> left, right;

//Constructors

public BinaryTreeNode(T obj) 
{
    element = obj;
    left = null;
    right = null;
}

public BinaryTreeNode(T obj, LinkedBinaryTree<T> left, LinkedBinaryTree<T> right) 
{
    element = obj;
    if (left == null)
        this.left = null;
    else
        this.left = left.getRootNode();

    if (right == null)
        this.right = null;
    else
        this.right = right.getRootNode();
}
```

And the methods in question

```
public void setLeft(BinaryTreeNode<T> node)
{
    left = node;
}

public void setRight(BinaryTreeNode<T> node) 
{
    right = node;
}
```

Comment: If you're asking about `left.root` and `right.root`, it's just getting the root of the left node, and the root of the right node. Each node has two child nodes (that's what makes it a binary tree). That's just getting the root of each of the children.

Comment: hmm sorry, this seems realy to broad, Imo the explanation would fill a chapter in a book(given I understand the question correctly). So I want to ask you with all respect if you can break your question down into smaller chunks?

Comment: I just don't understand how .root works, more specifically. How is this able to retrieve the root node from the left or right tree. In the LinkedBinaryTree class there is no method for .root

Comment: It's exactly what @Carcigenicate said.  `left` is a `LinkedBinaryTree` and `LinkedBinaryTree` has a `root` instance variable.  It's right there in your listing just before `modCount`.  So `left.root` accesses (or in this case reads) the value of that variable.

Comment: Well I don't know if the straight answer helps you, but well: its a member in a object.

Comment: @BobWantsToProgram Please don't take offense by this, but you'll need to take a step back and review the basics a bit before moving forward. `left.root` is accessing `root` of the `left` node. `.` accesses members of an object.

Comment: Ok so that is something I've never encountered haha.  Glad to hear it is as basic as that and this all makes a lot more sense. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction guys.. I have some reading to do.

Comment: @BobWantsToProgram https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html is probably a good starting point.

Comment: Note, it's the same as when you write `System.out.println`. That's accessing the `out` member of `System`, then the `println` method of `out`.

Comment: "To get to the value of an instance variable, you use dot notation, a form of addressing in which an instance or class variable name has two parts: a reference to an object or class on the left side of the dot and a variable on the right side of the dot.
Dot notation is a way to refer to an object's instance variables and methods using a dot (.) operator." I'm not sure how I've gone this long without knowing I could access instance variables from objects like this. This is amazing. Feeling quite stupid ATM about this and really regretting sending that email to my professor. *face palm*

Comment: Normally, you don't access variables like this, you use something like `left.getRoot()`.  But the tree class is accessing one of its own variables, so encapsulation isn't broken and it's all right to do.  Most every other  case you want to use a method `get()` to access a variable.  Just FYI.

Comment: So this citation answers your question? Sounds correct to me! My best!

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Probably why I've never encountered this way of accessing variables. Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 0):

This is a binary tree, as mentioned.

Every not-null node has a node to the left and right. Sometimes the value of nodes are null.

As explained in the comments of the question, you are calling the root variable from the type BinaryTreeNode. It would only make sense because the code was written.